# Analyzing Code Coverage from GRUNT

Tags: code-coverage, karma-runner, protractor

I have a JavaScript-heavy app being built via GRUNT. To test this app, I have tests written with Jasmine. The tests are being run via Karma and Protractor. I would like to show code coverage of these tests in the command-line. My question is, how do I do this? I can't figure out how to integrate code coverage details within my build process. Ideally, I would love to see code coverage of my unit tests and code covereage of my integration tests.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe code-coverage is possible at this time with Protractor.  Karma's code-coverage is made available via [istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul).  It appears one would have to write a custom reporter.  I agree this would be a nice feature.  I may take some time in the near future to see if I can crank this out. If I make any progress, I will post here again.